# Two VPNs using same subnet, NAT not possible on the customers end

Tags: vpn

I have a problem with a couple of VPN's.

I have looked at various similar questions, but most invariably suggest using NAT on the customers end. In my case that simply isn't possible, and I can **only** make changes on my side of the connection. I have put a description of my problem below.

If you know of other answers that do answer my query that I may have missed please point me in their direction.

*Description*

Currently I have a site-to-site VPN setup (on my firewall) between me and a customer1. On my side I have serverA (172.21.0.1) On my customer1's side I have a range (192.0.0.1 - 192.0.0.255) My customer1 only actually uses 192.0.0.10 but insists on having the whole range setup in the VPN.

I now have a new customer2 who needs a site-to-site VPN. On my side I have serverB (172.21.0.2) On my customer2's side I have a single server (192.0.0.15)

However, as you can see customer2's server is inside the range used for customer1.

I **can't alter** customer1's VPN, and customer2 is unable to change the IP Address of their server **(or use NAT to present a different IP Address)**.

Is there any way to resolve this by making changes **only to my side** of the VPN connections? Or am I stuck.

Comment: One or both of your customers needs to start acting in a sensible manner and renumbering. Using IANA reserved addresses is a big no-no. That's the best possible resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an it is easy.
**Run as administrator CMD**

```
route add -p 192.0.0.10/32 172.21.0.1    

route add -p 192.0.0.15/32 172.21.0.2
```

Now all traffic for 192.0.0.10 goes through 172.21.0.1 and for 192.0.0.15 goes through 172.21.0.2